# Report of who hasn't opened a mailing

Tags: civimail, searchkit

On several occasions I've seen users who want to know who did ***not*** open a bulk mailing. While this can be figured out in various ways, it should be possible to produce such a report using Search Kit, which would save time.  So far, I've not succeeded.  It would help to know which table holds the mailing open counts?  Can anyone help?

Comment: civicrm_mailing_event_opened ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know if I figure out a way to get a report of who did not open a mailing.  SK has this & related tables so it might be possible

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I've verified it against the Advanced Search method results... Noting the Advanced Search can be really inefficient and thus take a very long time on large mail lists so an SK approach is definitely good to have on hand.

[image]

Ref Advanced Search approach:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, tested and works!

Answer (score 0):

While Andy's solution might seem like a good one, it's important to know that this isn't really possible.  Here's an [article from Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/the-future-of-open-rates/) that explains why.  The problem isn't unique to Campaign Monitor - it affects all mail tools, including CiviMail.

In short - your mail tool doesn't actually know when email is opened, for privacy reasons.  What it *does* know is when remote images are loaded.  But a) many people don't load remote images (e.g. in Outlook it's the default not to). And b) to better protect privacy, in 2023 Apple changed all their products to load remote images even if the email isn't read.  GMail also has their own unique magic.

So in short - you're going to get lots of false positives and false negatives, and shouldn't rely on the "open rate" for anything except as an aggregated value.